# PHP - Unable to login after password reset with sha512

Tags: php, mysqli, passwords, salt, sha512

I'm building a simple login script and I am able to register and login no problem. However I am now trying to add a "Forgotten password" feature and I can't figure out why it's not working.

I am able to update the password in the mysql table using the same sha512 and salting method I use in my registration script but after its updated I can no longer login.

The login function that runs when a user tries to login is as follows:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT userID, firstName, pWord, salt FROM users WHERE email = ? AND conf = 1 LIMIT 1")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
    $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
    $stmt->store_result();
    // get variables from result.
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $firstName, $db_password, $salt);
    $stmt->fetch();

    // hash the password with the unique salt.
    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // Check if the password in the database matches 
            // the password the user submitted.
            if ($db_password == $password) {
                ... // Log user in
            }
}
}
```

The password part of my registration script:

```
$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));

    // Create salted password 
    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);

    // Insert the new user into the database 
    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (firstName, lastName, email, pWord, salt, accConf, conf) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 0)")) {

        $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $firstName, $lastName, $email, $password, $random_salt, $confirmation);
        $insert_stmt->execute();
... // Do something }
```

The password part of my reset script:

```
$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));

    // Create salted password 
    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);

    // Update the user's password
    if ($update = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE users SET pWord = ?, salt = ? WHERE email = ?')) {

        $update->bind_param('sss', $password, $random_salt, $email);
        $update->execute();
... //Do something }
```

I can see that in the database, the password **is** updating but when I try to login with the new password, my "Invalid login details error is showing up.

Is there a reason that my passwords would not work after updating?

Comment: In the line `if ($db_password == $password) {` -> where you set a `$db_password` variable? I cant't see it.

Comment: `$db_password` is defined in the `bind_param` from the SELECT statement in the login script

Comment: May i suggest using a different hashing method http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: I would create a table where I would store the passwords given at registrations and at reset passwords. If you do a reset password and copy the stored value, is it working at login?

Comment: Why are you not using `password_hash` and `password_verify`? Rolling your own password hashing is very dangerous and should be left to the pros.

Comment: Nathan you mean the bind_result, right?

Comment: Just in case, check if, in your base, your password is complet. If you have design field like varchar(10), the base save the 10 first characters but not the entire password. So when you try to login, you compare 2 differents string (ex : 4984984988 in your base and 498498498874516 when you hash the password again). So, check if your varchar in base can add the entiere password hashed

Comment: I do mean bind_result. My bad! With regards to the the better hashing methods I'll look into that right now! Thanks!

Comment: @Xenofexs the database field has the datatype for VARCHAR(250) if that's what you mean. It should contain enough character storage to hold the whole password no?

Comment: I can't know. echo your hashed password and compare him with your base. If it is shorter in your base, transform varchar to text

Comment: Echoed hashed password and password in database are identical. I've tried changing it to text anyway incase but no luck